# Manage Authorization To folders in Azure Data Lake from Excel

Tags: excel, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-data-lake

I am developing an Azure data lake and I want to connect Excel to the data lake.

1. How do you authorize users too see the data from Excel?
   I have used two test users and given them different access to the resource group, the services etc, and they just don't get access. Only I, myself have access.
2. Is it possible to restrict the access so that excel can only see one specific folder in the data lake?
   The normal way to do this is using an app registration, but I can not see how to connect an app to excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Users must be authenticated via ADFS and granted global permissions. You can specify O365 credentials and grant AAD access.
   https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/freddyk/2018/06/29/aad-authentication/
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/analysis-services/analysis-services-manage-users
2. You can apply access control in Azure Data Lake so that users can only see certain folders. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-access-control#common-scenarios-related-to-permissions